# R error SQLSatellite cannot read data chunk

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

I have an SSIS 2015 package that calls a Stored Proc in SQL Server 2016.
When I run the SSIS package I get these two messages:

> Error: A 'R' script error occurred during execution   of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
>
> Error: STDERR message(s) from external script: 
>   Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : bad allocation
>   Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
>   Execution halted

So I ran the stored proc in SSMS but get these messages.

> A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
>
> STDERR message(s) from external script: 
>   SqlSatellite cannot read data chunk.  Error code:0x80004004.
>
> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : SqlSatellite cannot read data chunk.  Error code:0x80004004.
>   Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call

I have run the R scripts input query in SSMS which returns data, I do not believe I am missing any columns in the R script which I believe was working previously.
But being new to R I have no idea how to diagnose what may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research on the errors and found some information at http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/11/11/microsoft-sql-server-r-services-internals-xiii/.
The suspicion was that it may not be a code issue, more a data issue.  A considerable amount of testing indicated it was the amount of data I was analyzing with the R script, I was able to restrict the amount of data using some date parameters and finished the data loads.
Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using Python in SQL Server 2017. I figured out it was because my `WITH RESULT SETS` statement did not fit my `OutputDataSet`.